# Boost.Tests vc142 from Vcpkg on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, boost-test, vcpkg, test-explorer

I'm new to both vcpkg and boost library and I've been researching, and trying, how to setup boost-unit-tests-framework on VS 2019 but all docs seem out of date.

My goal is to run boost tests from test explorer in visual studio.

### Vcpkg

1. Cloned Vcpkg and ran *bootstrap-vcpkg.bat*
2. Ran *vcpkg integrate install* to configure Visual Studio with the library and include paths of the installed packages

#### Compiling tests [Debug only]

Following: [ms-docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-use-boost-test-for-cpp?view=vs-2019#create-a-separate-test-project)

- Installed boost-test package using `vcpkg install boost-test:x64-windows-static`
- Added the following elements to the `<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">` in my unit test project:

```
   <VcpkgTriplet>x64-windows-static</VcpkgTriplet>
   <VcpkgEnabled>true</VcpkgEnabled>
```

- Set *C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library* to `Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)`
- Added *Additional include directories* -> `$(VcpkgRoot)include\` that resolves to `C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\include\`
- Added *Linker -> Additional Library Directories* -> `$(VcpkgRoot)debug\lib\` that resolves to `C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\debug\lib\`
- Added *Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies* -> `boost_unit_test_framework-vc140-mt-gd.lib;boost_regex-vc140-mt-gd.lib;boost_exception-vc140-mt-gd.lib;boost_container-vc140-mt-gd.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)`
- Added test code:

```
    #define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTest
    #include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
    #include <string>

    class MyClass
    {
        std::string m_name = "Jim";
    public:
        std::string get_value() const { return m_name; }
        void set_value(std::string const &name) { m_name = name; }
    };

    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(my_boost_test)
    {
        std::string expected_value = "Bill";

        MyClass mc;
        BOOST_CHECK(expected_value == mc.get_value());
        BOOST_TEST(expected_value == mc.get_value());
        mc.set_value(expected_value);
        BOOST_TEST(expected_value == mc.get_value());
    }
```

#### Console run

Everything runs fine running the test exe from console:
[image]

#### VS Test explorer

Nothing shows up on the test-explorer, even if my boost test-adapter is intalled..
[image: empty-test-explorer]

Has anyone solved this yet??

One alternative I've found is to run the *test.exe* as part of the build process like boost-docs mention. Not quite as useful for my team.

Comment: On the bottom panel (the output), it says `show output from build`. This is a drop down, and I believe there is another option for the output. On the left side, there is a `play` button, doesn't it run all the discovered boost.test modules?

Comment: From the test viewer on the left you can see it does not discover the tests.